# Generate sequence (1,301,2, 302, 3, 303, 4,304 ...) in R

Tags: r, sequence

I am trying to generate the sequence:

```
 1,301,2,302,3,303,4,304 ... 300,600
```

in R. Is there a quick easy way to do this without using a for loop?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `rbind` to alternate between the values

```
as.vector(rbind(1:300, 301:600))
```

Comment: You may also use `c` instead of  `as.vector` to make it shorter.

Comment: Or `c(rbind(x <- 1:300, x+300))`, which assures you maintain the relationship between the vectors if you decide to change `x`.

Comment: @JasonMorgan; although this will create (or overwrite) a variable `x` in the global environment.  Perhaps a middle ground is `c(rbind(1:300, (1:300)+300))`

Answer (score 5):

Another way to do it with `rep`, `seq` and `c`:

```
rep(seq(300),each=2)+c(0,300)
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use:

```
c(0,300) + rep(1:300, each=2)
```